# Cannot use a scalar value as an array, what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: php

```
 <?php
$file = file("lliga.txt");
/*Convertir en un array de arrays */
$clave = array();
foreach($file as $clave => $partido){
    $file[$clave] = explode(",",$partido);  
}

/*Crear el array $clasificacion*/
foreach($file as $clave => $partido){
    $equipoLocal = $partido[$clave][0];
    $equipoVisitante = $partido[$clave][1];
    $golesEquipoLocal = $partido[$clave][2];
    $golesEquipoVisitante = $partido[$clave][3];
        
    //Solo si no existe el equipo Local lo inicilizo todo a 0
    //array_key_exists
    if (array_key_exists($equipoLocal, $partido)) {
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['PG'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['PP'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['PE'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['P'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['GF'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['GC'] = 0;
            
    }
    if (array_key_exists($equipoVisitante,$partido)){
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['PG'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['PP'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['PE'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['P'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['GF'] = 0;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['GC'] = 0;
    }
    //Solo si no existe el equipo Visitante lo inicilizo todo a 0
    //Empiezas a mirar a resultados
        
    if ($golesEquipoLocal  > $golesEquipoVisitante){
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['PG']++;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['P']++;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['GF']++;
    }
    if ($golesEquipoLocal == $golesEquipoVisitante){
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['PE']++;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['GF']++;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['P'] = $clave[$equipoLocal]['P'] +1;
        $clave[$equipoLocal]['GC']++;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['PE']++;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['GF']++;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['GC']++;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['P']= $clave[$equipoVisitante]['P']+1;
            
    }
    if ($golesEquipoLocal < $golesEquipoVisitante){
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['PG']++;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['P']++;
        $clave[$equipoVisitante]['GF']++;
        $classi = fopen("classi.txt", "a");
        $fp = $equipoVisitante;
        fwrite($classi, $fp);
        fwrite($classi, $fp);
        fclose($classi);
    }
    $paco=[];
    array_multisort($partido, SORT_ASC, $paco);
    
    print_r($partido);
}
?>
```

Here's my code, as you can see, i have 3 or 4 arrays, and the code **works** fine, however i get this error `Cannot use a scalar value as an array` and i don't know why, i already searched in google but i don't get what i'm doing wrong.. any idea? I already tried to sort too, but it doesn't work, and i already readed the php manual but i don't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Please ALWAYS show us ALL the error mesage not a summary. Then, if at all possible indicte the line of code that the line number in the error message indictaes in the code you show

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 55 and if you run this code, you will see a lot more of this error in every line..

Comment: We cannot run this code without the text file `lliga.txt`

Comment: then should i upload the file?

Comment: Also, the `foreach` lacks a closing bracket. Happy to help, but please make sure we can run your code without parsing or syntax errors . As for the data: Just provide some meaningful excerpt.

Comment: An example of it might help, but not all the file

Comment: The line 55 of the code is that one: `$clave[$equipoVisitante]['PG']++;`

Comment: Then likely as not, $clave is not an array

Comment: Can you add some data to support this question?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is in this code.
Using `$clave` in the `foreach($file as $clave => $partido){` line destroys and then recreates `$clave` as a SCALAR Variable each time round the loop.

Then you use it again in line 10 `foreach($file as $clave => $partido){` and destroy it all over again

```
$file = file("lliga.txt");
/*Convertir en un array de arrays */
$clave = array();
foreach($file as $clave => $partido){
    $file[$clave] = explode(",",$partido);  
}

/*Crear el array $clasificacion*/
foreach($file as $clave => $partido){
```

So try this for example

```
$file = file("lliga.txt");
$clave = array();
foreach($file as $key => $partido){
    $clave[$key] = explode(",",$partido);  
}

/*Crear el array $clasificacion*/
foreach($clave as $partido){
```

Or as the $key will just be 0,1,2,3,..... You could slightly simplify

```
$file = file("lliga.txt");
$clave = array();
foreach($file as $partido){
    $clave[] = explode(",",$partido);  
}

/*Crear el array $clasificacion*/
foreach($clave as $partido){
```

> Or, as the input appears to be a file of newline terminated, Comma Delimited Values, You may also benefit from reading up on [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: Why i quit `clave` for `key`? doesn't that just delete all the info i got in `clave`?

Comment: No, using `$clave` in the `foreach($file as $clave => $partido){` line destroys and then recreates `$clave` as a SCALAR Variable each time round the loop :)

Comment: I see, i did that but i still getting the same error in other lanes, also the print_r stops working after changing this value.

Comment: Ok so show me a sample of the input file please, just 3 or 4 lines

Comment: Just spotted the second foreach is again destroying the `$clave` amended my answer